# matlab wprcoef -> python?

Tags: python, matlab

I have a few questions. 
I am studying [this](https://github.com/MrTangsai/BearLSTM)
I want to change. "wave.m" (matlab) to "wave.py" (python)3.x

But I am having difficulties. 
   This is my matlab code:

```
 clear;clc;
    load data;
    Fre=48000;
    cycle=1/Fre;
    length=size(data,2);
    time=0:cycle:(length-1)*cycle;
    for i=1:size(data,1)
    tree=wpdec(data(i,:),3,'db10');
    z=1
    for j=0:2^3-1
        coef=wprcoef(tree,[3,j]);
        energy(z)=sqrt(sum(abs(coef).^2));
        z=z+1;
    end
    %wavedata(i,:)=energy./sum(energy)
    wavedata(i,:)=mapstd(energy)
    end
    save('wavedata.mat','wavedata');
```

I see it and I'm making it in python. 
This is my Python code:

```
mat_file  = io.loadmat('data.mat')
input_mat = mat_file['data']

data = np.concatenate(input_mat, axis=0) 

Fre = 48000
cycle = 1/Fre
length = data.size

time = ? 

for i in range(length):
   tree = pywt.dwt(data[i:],'db10',3)
   z=1 
   for j in range(7):
      coef = ? 
      z = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.abs(coef)**2))/len(coef[-j]) 
      z = z+1
```

How do I write the time and coef parts?
In my book, I mentioned that wavelet can be classified according to signal characteristics.
What I want is to classify the vibration signal into wavelets.

Comment: `time` is easy: `np.arange(0,(length-1)*cycle,cycle)`, not that it's used anywhere later. The real problem is that [`wprcoef`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wprcoef.html) is a special function in the wavelet toolbox. You'll need to see if that's implemented anywhere; your best chances are somewhere in the scipy library.

Comment: There is no example code in the book. It's just an explanation. ㅜㅜ

Comment: I understand that, still this is something you'll have to look into yourself. The MATLAB documentation I linked to is usually pretty good, you might even find references in it to see what it implements. And googling "python wavelet" will probably give you options in python (scipy or not), and you'll have to check each to see if it's appropriate for your problem.

Comment: for `wprcoef`, you will have to learn wavelet transform if you can't find a wavelet package in python. The algorithm is everywhere on the internet.